# Передача изображения из представления в метод действС#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Есть некое представление, которое получает пользовательское изображение через `<input type="file" value="Добавить аватар" />` и потом передает его на метод действия, но почему то на метод постоянно приходить null, а не изображение.

Представление:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.EditorForModel()
<label>Повторите пароль</label><br>
@Html.Password("Повторите пароль")
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="file" value="Добавить аватар" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Зарегестрироваться" />
}
```

Метод действия, который обрабатывает отправленную форму:

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Registr(User user, HttpPostedFileBase image)
        {
            if (image != null)
            {
                user.IconUserType = image.ContentType;
                user.IconUserData = new byte[image.ContentLength];
                image.InputStream.Read(user.IconUserData, 0, image.ContentLength);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для успешной связки (binding) элементов запроса и параметров акшн метода (по умолчанию) они должны одинаково называться.

```
<input type="file" value="Добавить аватар" name="image"/>
```